# Drupal Background Image as Block or Node

Tags: drupal-6, cck, background-image

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to make editable background images in my custom Drupal 6 theme. My client wants to use a different background image on each main section on his website (with multiple content types: page, blog, image gallery), and to keep everything dynamic, I want the background images to be editable.

What I'd like to do is add a background image field to various content types that allows a user to reference an image from the content library or upload a new image (similar to ImageAssist), and have it apply to a region in my template. Any suggestions on the best approach for this?

Is there a way to make a custom content type into a dynamic background image block? I am using the Image, Image Cache, Views, CCK, Image Assist, Panels, Filefield, and Imagefield modules.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

are usign the function phptemplate_preprocess ? maybe i missed it but there is nu such function on drupals's API site.
I think you should use phptemplate_preprocess_page, which should be implemented as:
'function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars)' and placed in your template.php which is in your theme dir.
most likely the function already exists there and you should add the following lines at the end of it:
`global $base_url;

if (!empty($vars['node']->type)) {

  if (($vars['node']->type == 'CONTENT-TYPE-A') || ($vars['node']->type == 'CONTENT-TYPE-B') {

    $vars['background'] = $base_url."/".$vars['node']->field_background[0]['filepath'];
   }

 }`
note that field_background is a cck field

regarding your page.tpl.php, i prefer not to enter the image in the body tag. i put it inside in an a div, this will allow more flexibility ( for example if you would like the image to be 20px below the top of the browser). example:
`<div id="main" >

    <div id="page" style='background: url("<?php print $background ?>") no-repeat;'>`

hope this helps
avner

Answer (score 1):

I am working on such a site myself these days.
What i did is:
1. create content field for this image in which the site admin can upload a new background
2. in the template.php i added the image location to the a new $var['background'] i created
3. in the pape.tpl.php i added a div inside the body that contains all page's content, 
4. in the a bove div i added a style and printed $background as the background's value
example(replaved <> with [] to avoid auto code removal):
  [body class="[?php print $body_classes; ?]"]
    [div id="page" style='background: url("[?php print $background ?]") no-repeat;']
    [/div]
  [/body]
hope this helps
Avner

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But are you only using one image? I am hoping to somehow make it easy to put a different image on each section. When you say "image location," do you mean hard-coding a url?

Comment: not at all, as i explained in my comment, the background can be changed and entered as a variable(in my example $background).
post your template.php and i will try and help you out with the code

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am hard-coding a url, which is pretty pointless until I figure out how to make it dynamic. Here is a portion of my template.php file:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['background'] = base_path().'sites/default/files/wood-med.jpg';
   //...
}
```

And here is the relevant section of my page.tpl.php file:

```
  </head>

    <body class="<?php print $body_classes ?>" style='background-image: url("<?php print $background ?>");background-repeat: repeat-y;'>
      <div id="pageWrapper">
      // ....
```

I created a Background Image node type and want to use it to supply a Page, Image, or Gallery node with a list of images to choose from. Any ideas on how to hook this up?

Answer (score 0):

a simpler and cleaner way is to add in the template.php inside the phptemplate_preprocess_page() function:

`if (isset($node->field_background[0]['filepath']) ){
        $vars['styles'] .= ' ';
          $vars['styles'] .= 'div#page{background: url("'.$base_url.'/'.$node->field_background[0]['filepath'].'");}';
        $vars['styles'] .= '';
        }`